# Google Spreadsheet - To execute a custom function only in the expanded row group

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

I have a form where my team fills in daily sales activity data.
I have to fetch the data of each member and display it another sheet.
Though I can do it with query, I have written a custom function that takes 3 arguments and search in the form responses and returns an array of data. Daily(name,week,day) is my function.
Every time the formula is called, the search happens on the entire form response data.

Now the issue is the formula is used 13*365(13 people ad 365 days) times in the sheet.

I am unable to stop the function from executing again and again. I have grouped the rows month wise, also created named ranges. either of the ways, can I execute the formula only in this expanded rows/named ranges using Apps script???? [Attached the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHuKa.png)

Comment: If the function is being called in a cell, it will be executed no matter what. What you could do is to not call this function for non-expanded rows, or modify your function so that it is called in less cells and it returns data for multiple cells. More information would be needed though, in order to help you here. Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet, clearly indicating the desired outcome.

Comment: @lamblichus - Returns data to multiple cells needs a kind of sorting on days/date of the week. Please do take a look at the sheet. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rabaDxOPL3gFoT3u2pVDvhNpsqvQjsn_HO05oHXp0no/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you thought of using an `onEdit` trigger instead of a custom function?

Comment: Yes, I tried using all three - On Edit, On change, On Form submit - Doesn't stop running :(

Comment: What do you mean by `Doesn't stop running`? The idea behind implementing a trigger is to get rid of the custom functions and do the same actions using a trigger. What doesn't stop running in this case?

Comment: I mean to say, The custom function doesn't stop executing even after putting a trigger. I have even tried a time driven trigger.

Comment: The idea behind using a trigger is removing your custom function, and doing whatever this custom function is doing via trigger. If you don't remove it, of course it won't stop executing.

Comment: No, my query is quite different from the direction of this discussion is heading. I have a custom function which I have used 365*13 times in a sheet, 
I dont want it to execute on the entire sheet every time I open the sheet.. I want to execute only in the specific rows which is not hidden

Comment: Is there a way to read the cell value like "B2" or row number in which  the function call is made.

Comment: I understand that, but what you're asking for is not possible. That's why I mentioned using a trigger to do what the custom function is currently doing. And about your last comment, no, there's no way for the custom function to know the cell reference where it is called.

Comment: Thank you, then I will just set the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code, like i would go from row 1 to max and check every row. If  it is not hidden, you can execute your code, else its skipped.

Its working for me. Depends on your code you have to adaped it.

```
function HiddenRowSkipper() {
  var devTest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DevTest");

  var maxRow = devTest.getMaxRows();

  for(var i = 1; i < maxRow; i++){
    if(devTest.isRowHiddenByUser(i) == false){
      //Execute your code on the Row "i" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how shall I use this to stop the function from executing on other rows.

Comment: I hope that the code Sample help you, finde a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you Malte, but this will slow down my function execution even further. I have used my custom function 365*13 times..  Is there any way to find the cell value like "B2" or row number where the function call is made.